# Does trigonometric substitution make an indefinite integral definite?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I want to solve the integral
$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, \mathrm dx$$
using the trigonometric substitution $x=\sin{t}$ with $t\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ since the function sine is invertible in $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right].$

**Now my question is:** I know that I have to write that $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, \mathrm dx$ equals $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{\sin{t}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{t}}}\cos{t}\, \mathrm dt$ instead of $\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sin{t}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{t}}}\cos{t}\, \mathrm dt.$ But why is the integral still indefinite? When I tranform $x$ to $t\in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}],$ I get an integrand whose variable is defined in this particular interval, so I would say that the integral becomes definite and it is no longer indefinite.

Comment: Because in the given integral, you have no bounds, it does *not* become  a definite integral. $t$  is restrivted to an integral, but this doesn't mean there are bpounds. Anyway, in the given integral, $x$ is restricted to the interval $(-1,1)$, due to the square root.

Comment: Ok thanks but the fact that I am passing from $x$ (supposing that relly every real value is admitted for $x$ ) to $t$ that is defined only in an interval is allowed?

Comment: But, as I mentioned, the original integrand is defined only in a finite interval. Furthermore, the restriction of $t$ to the interval $(-\dfrac\pi 2,\dfrac\pi 2)$ is there to ensure the substitution is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

For real domain, the original integral could be $$\int_a^b\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ where $-1\le a,b\le1$

Also, if trigonometric substitution is not mandatory, for $$\int\dfrac{dx}{x^{2n+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}},$$ we can choose $\sqrt{1-x^2}=y$ to eliminate the radical

Comment: Do you mean that even if I don't have a definite integral I have to imagine that it is definite because $a\leq x\leq b$?

Answer (score 1):

> $$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, \mathrm dx\tag1$$
> using the substitution $x=\sin{t}$ with $t\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ $$\int \frac{\cos{t}}{\sin{t}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{t}}} \mathrm dt\tag2$$

Restricting $(2)$'s domain to $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ (actually, this can be changed to any interval where $\sin$ is invertible and has range $[-1,1]$) is imposed *purely* so that if $(1)$ is given integration limits, we will choose a valid corresponding pair of integration limits for $(2);$ for example, $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos{t}}{\sin{t}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{t}}} \mathrm dt\ne \int_{0.25}^{0.5} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, \mathrm dx\ne \int_{3\pi-\arcsin(0.25)}^{\arcsin(0.5)} \frac{\cos{t}}{\sin{t}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{t}}} \mathrm dt$$ even though $$\sin\big(3\pi-\arcsin(0.25)\big)=0.25.$$

On the other hand, if $(2)$ is considered without regard to $(1),$ then its domain is $\mathbb R{\setminus}\left\{\frac{k\pi}2\mid k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$

The domain of $(1)$ is $(-1,0)\cup(0,1).$

[Having a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ as domain does not make any of the above indefinite integrals definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4372146/21813) though. An indefinite integral is just a general antiderivative, which has the same domain as its integrand (for example, the domain of $\int\frac1x\,\mathrm dx$ excludes $0,$ so it is illegal to plug in $-3$ and $5$ as its integration limits). In contrast, a definite integral denotes an area associated with its integration limits.