# Does a function have an infinite number of definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, infinity

Suppose, I have a function $\cos(x)$. Now,

$$\int{\cos(x)dx}$$

$$\sin(x)+c\\ [\text{Indefinite integral of cos(x)}]\\ [\text{where c is a constant}]$$

Now, there could be an infinite number of values for $c$. For example, $c=1,2,-2,\pi,-\pi, 0, \frac{1}{3}, 7, 500, ...$

And using each value of $c$, we can formulate an infinite number of definite integrals of $\cos(x)$:

$$\sin(x)+1[\text{Definite integral of cos(x)}]$$

$$\sin(x)+\pi[\text{Definite integral of cos(x)}]$$

$$\sin(x)+\frac{1}{3}[\text{Definite integral of cos(x)}]$$

$$...$$

So, $\cos(x)$ has an infinite number of definite integrals, hasn't it?

Comment: These aren't definite integrals.  They are "antiderivatives" or "indefinite integrals".  And yes, an integrable function has infinitely many antiderivatives, differing only by a vertical shift of their graphs.

Comment: The term "definite integral" is not used as you do. It is used when there are lower and upper limits of integration, and result is unique.

Comment: @EricTowers So, even if the constant is specified (for example $c=3$), $\sin(x)+3$ will still be called an indefinite integral of $\cos(x)$?

Comment: Yes.  A definite integral is a number, obtained by integrating over an interval.  An indefinite integral is a function.

Comment: @EricTowers Sir I posted another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4353840/768162) related to your comment. If you want, you can check it out.

Comment: @Coffeemath, if the upper and lower limits (or at least one limit) are variables, is it still called a definite integral?

Comment: @EricTowers Kind sir, I had another question. Would you consider $\int_{0}^{x}f(x)dx$, where x is a variable, a definite integral?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic : I would call that malformed.  The variable $x$ has been bound incompatibly in two contexts.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh sorry, my bad: $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$, where $x$ is a variable. Would you consider this a definite integral sir?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic : When I teach calculus, this is called an "accumulation function" and is described as being intermediate between a definite integral and an antiderivative.  One *could* call it a parametrized definite integral, but the nomenclatural knots regarding variable/parameter/constant are just as much philosophical time-wasting as your current efforts to try to nail down nomenclature for integrals.  We write down the expressions to side-step such time-wasting.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: There is no uniform definitions, as you can tell from comments. It is very easy to answer your question if you add the *definition* of "indefinite integrals" in *your* book. Which book are you reading and where is the first place this notion appears in the book?

Comment: @EricTowers I understand sir. "We write down the expressions to side-step such time-wasting": sir I could not understand exactly what you were saying here. Could you kindly explain it please sir?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic : $\int_0^x \; f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$  is entirely unambiguous.  It doesn't matter if I call it an accumulation function, a cat, or Fred.  The expression precisely and unambiguously declares what is meant.  Pretending the minutia of nomenclature is wisdom is wasting time.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: What book are you using?

Comment: @banana It's a relatively unknown Bangladeshi book.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: okay. So no way to have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\int{\cos(x)\,\mathrm dx}=\sin(x)+c\\ [\text{Indefinite integral of cos(x)}]\\ [\text{where c is a constant}]$$
> even if the constant is specified (for example $c=3),$ will $\sin(x)+3$ still be called an indefinite integral of $\cos(x)?$

When the indefinite integral $\int{\cos(x)\,\mathrm dx}$ is instantiated as $\sin(x)+3,$ it becomes a particular antiderivative. An indefinite integral is represents every antiderivative of its integrand, and the $C$ in its specification is more accurately called an *arbitrary* constant or a parameter.

(If a function is defined on an interval and has an antiderivative, then its antiderivative is unique up to an additive constant and independent arbitrary constants aren't required in the general specification of its antiderivatives.)

Instantiating $\int{\cos(x)\,\mathrm dx}$ doesn't make it a definite integral, since the latter is defined with reference to specified integration limits (the $a$ and $b$ in $\int_a^bf\,)$ and denotes an area related to them.

(It's worth noting that a definite integral isn't actually a particular instance of an indefinite integral; for example, for \begin{align}f(x)&= \begin{cases} 0, &x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1];\\ 1, &x=0,\end{cases}\end{align}$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$ even while $f$ has no antiderivative and so no indefinite integral.)

> $\displaystyle∫^x_0f(t)\,\mathrm dt.$ Would you consider this a definite integral?

This function of $x$ is literally a definite integral.

If $f$ is a continuous function, then by the Fundamental Thereom of Calculus Part 1, $∫^x_0f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is also an antiderivative of $f$ and, being a single antiderivative, isn't an indefinite integral.

P.S. Read more here: [What does the antiderivative represent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283261/21813)

Comment: To continue the discussion where the OP was starting, if we were to imagine a definite integral to be a function of its integration limits (i.e., $g(a, b)$), then there would only be one definite integral, because the subtraction would remove the constant of integration.
$$g(a, b) = \int_a^b \cos(x)\,dx = \left(\sin(b) + C\right) - \left(\sin(a) + C\right)$$
$$ = \sin(b) - \sin(a) + C - C = \sin(b) - \sin(a)$$